# R - spatstat: Calculate density for a new point

Tags: r, spatstat

Is it possible to use `spatstat` to estimate the intensity function for a give `ppp` object and calculate its value considering a new point? For example, can I evaluate `D` at `new_point`:

```r
# packages
library(spatstat)

# define a random point within Window(swedishpines)
new_point <- ppp(x = 45, y = 45, window = Window(swedishpines))

# estimate density
(D <- density(swedishpines))
#> real-valued pixel image
#> 128 x 128 pixel array (ny, nx)
#> enclosing rectangle: [0, 96] x [0, 100] units (one unit = 0.1 metres)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

I was thinking that maybe I can `superimpose()` the two `ppp` objects (i.e. `swedishpines` and `new_point`) and then run `density` setting `at = "points"` and `weights = c(rep(1, points(swedishpines)), 0)` but I'm not sure if that's the suggested approach (and I'm not sure if the appended point is ignored during the estimation process).

I know that it may sound like a trivial question, but I read some docs and didn't find an answer or a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.

The first is simply to take the pixel image of intensity, and extract the pixel values at the desired locations using `[`:

```
D <- density(swedishpines)
v <- D[new_points]
```

See the help for `density.ppp` and `[.im`.

The other way is to use `densityfun`:

```
f <- densityfun(swedishpines)
v <- f(new_points)
```

See the help for `densityfun.ppp`

The first route is more efficient and the second way is more accurate.

*Technical issue*: if some of the `new_points` could lie outside the window of `swedishpines` then the value at these points is (mathematically) undefined. Both of the methods described above will simply ignore such points, and the resulting vector `v` will be shorter than the number of new points. If you need to handle this continengcy, the easiest way is to use `D[new_points, drop=FALSE]` which returns `NA` values for such locations.

Comment: Thank you very much.